# read IP address and check if valid/between range

Tags: bash, loops, if-statement, ip-address

My current script:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter VPS IP address:"
read userinput
lookupip="vps $userinput"

if [[ $userinput -lt 80.* || $userinput -gt 255.* ]] #checks input is in the range
 then
   echo "Input outside acceptable range."
 else

#The grep removes all from VPS tool output except primary IP address

$lookupip | grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' | sed '1 ! d' | xargs ping -oc 1000 -Q

fi
```

The lowest IP address range is in the 80.X.X.X range, I've tried using:

8*
80*
80.*.*.*

But it always errors with:

```
line 10: [[: 80.X.X.X: syntax error in expression (error token is ".X.X.X")
```

What would be the best way to define a range of IP address less than (lt) and gt (greater than)?

Comment: Don't hide the command you are running in a variable. It makes you code less readable, and doesn't work as often as you think it should. Just type out `vps $userinput | grep ...`

Comment: OK, that makes sense, but how do I then call it neatly from within an if loop?

Answer (score 2):

if you just want to check if the IP address is valid or not, you can use ipcalc command in bash to check this.

```
ipcalc -c $userinput
example
ipcalc -c 10.20.30.401
ipcalc: bad IPv4 address: 10.20.30.401
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably not the best solution, but as a quick fix for your script should do:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash
echo -n "Enter VPS IP address:"
read userinput
lookupip="vps $userinput"
first_octet=`echo "$userinput" | cut -d'.' -f1`

if [[ $first_octet -lt 80 || $first_octet -gt 255 ]]
 then
   echo "Input outside acceptable range."
 else

#The grep removes all from VPS tool output except primary IP address

$lookupip | grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' | sed '1 ! d' | xargs ping -oc 1000 -Q

fi
```

EDITED: **a better solution** would be to take all three IP addresses (the one under inspection, lowest and highest) as parameters, convert them to 32bit number (that's what `inet_aton()` function does) and check ranges:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/bash

inet_aton ()
{
    local IFS=. ipaddr ip32 i
    ipaddr=($1)
    for i in 3 2 1 0
    do
        (( ip32 += ipaddr[3-i] * (256 ** i) ))
    done

    return $ip32
}

echo -n "Enter VPS IP address, min IP address, max IP address:"
read userinput

ip1=`echo "$userinput" | cut -d' ' -f1`
ip2=`echo "$userinput" | cut -d' ' -f2`
ip3=`echo "$userinput" | cut -d' ' -f3`

lookupip="vps $ip1"

ip=`inet_aton $ip1`
min=`inet_aton $ip2`
max=`inet_aton $ip3`

if [[ $ip -lt $min || $ip -gt $max ]]
 then
   echo "Input outside acceptable range."
 else

#The grep removes all from VPS tool output except primary IP address

$lookupip | grep -E -o '(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)' | sed '1 ! d' | xargs ping -oc 1000 -Q

fi
```

The only difference would be that you have to enter 3 IP addresses, not one as before. Of course, the lowest and highest IP addresses could be hard-coded or taken from elsewhere, but I leave that, along with parameter validation and error checking, up to you.

Comment: That works, thanks :) Ideally it would view the whole IP address and check if it is in a list of ranges I have. There are 10 unique ranges which only vary on the 3rd and 4th octet.

Comment: Use `IFS="." read -a octets <<< $userinput`. Then check each of `${octets[0]}`, `${octets[1]}`, etc. individually.

Answer (score 0):

For Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt install grepcidr ipcalc
```

And then:

```
RANGE="192.168.1.210-192.168.1.250"
IP="192.168.1.250"

grepcidr "$(ipcalc -r "$RANGE" | tail -n+2)" <(echo "$IP") >/dev/null && echo "in" || echo "out"
```